# Join 3 tables using javax.persistence in a OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

The 3 tables are "analyticalgroups", "labinstructions", "observedproperties". Each table has an "id" primary key column.

I'd like to use a 4th table ("analyticalgroups_observedproperties_labinstructions") to store the OneToMany relationship. Ultimately I'd like the output to be structured something like this:

```
analyticalGroup: {
  id: "...",
  observedPropertyLabInstructions: [
    {observedProperty, labInstruction},
    {observedProperty, labInstruction},
    {observedProperty, labInstruction},
    ...etc...
  ]
}
```

I've followed some examples online, but can't get this to work. The problem is when I try this I get the following error:

> "message" : "Error occurred at repository: PSQLException: ERROR: column observedpr0_.observedpropertyentitylabinstructionentitymap_id does not exist\n  Position: 6550",
>     "errorCode" : "gaia.domain.exceptions.RepositoryException",

---

Here's the structure for the join table.

```
CREATE TABLE analyticalgroups_observedproperties_labinstructions
(
  analyticalgroupid character varying(36) NOT NULL,
  labinstructionid character varying(36) NOT NULL,
  observedpropertyid character varying(36) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_analyticalgroups_observedproperties_labinstructions_groupid FOREIGN KEY (analyticalgroupid)
      REFERENCES analyticalgroups (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_analyticalgroups_observedproperties_labinstructions_labinstr FOREIGN KEY (labinstructionid)
      REFERENCES labinstructions (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_analyticalgroups_observedproperties_labinstructions_observed FOREIGN KEY (observedpropertyid)
      REFERENCES observedproperties (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

---

```
@Entity
@Data
public class AnalyticalGroupEntity {

    public static final String ENTITY_NAME = "analyticalGroups";
    public static final String JOIN_OBSERVEDPROPERTIES_LABINSTRUCTIONS_TABLE_NAME =
            ENTITY_NAME +
                    IDomainEntity.UNDERSCORE +
                    ObservedPropertyEntity.ENTITY_NAME +
                    IDomainEntity.UNDERSCORE +
                    LabInstructionEntity.ENTITY_NAME;

    @Id
    @Column(name = IDomainEntity.ID_KEY, nullable = false, columnDefinition = IDomainEntity.COLUMN_TYPE_UUID)
    private String id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = JOIN_OBSERVEDPROPERTIES_LABINSTRUCTIONS_TABLE_NAME,
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = LabInstructionEntity.ID_KEY, referencedColumnName = IDomainEntity.ID_KEY, table = "labinstructions")
    )
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = ObservedPropertyEntity.ID_KEY, referencedColumnName = IDomainEntity.ID_KEY, table = "observedproperties")
    private Map<ObservedPropertyEntity, LabInstructionEntity> observedPropertyLabInstructions;

}
```

Hopefully I've laid this all out as clearly as necessary.
Your help is much appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Can you update your question to clearly show the relationship between the tables?

Comment: What would make this clearer for you? The join table 'analyticalgroups_observedproperties_labinstructions' shows 3 foreign keys, 1 to each of the other 3 tables.

Answer (score 0):

**edit** Actually... it turns out this doesn't work. It successfully gets the data I want, buuuuut it also deletes every row in the join table whenever I make a GET request *flip table*

So bizarre!

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = JOIN_OBSERVEDPROPERTIES_LABINSTRUCTIONS_TABLE_NAME,
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "analyticalgroupid", referencedColumnName = IDomainEntity.ID_KEY, table = "labinstructions"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = LabInstructionEntity.ID_KEY, referencedColumnName = IDomainEntity.ID_KEY, table = "labinstructions")
)
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = ObservedPropertyEntity.ID_KEY, referencedColumnName = IDomainEntity.ID_KEY, table = "observedproperties")
private Map<ObservedPropertyEntity, LabInstructionEntity> observedPropertyEntityLabInstructionEntityMap;
```